# Stream json.dumps(obj) of an object by chunks

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have a large object `obj` that I want to send over the aiohttp.session.post() request as data input. Currently I am doing it like following:

```
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers) as response:
                resp = await response.json()
```

But this obviously serializes the object into a large string and takes up memory. What I want to achieve is to stream `data` into the request by chunks. I've read about `ijson` which iteratively parses the json by objects, but I just need to stream it in, say, 4096 byte chunks.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [streaming API](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#streaming-uploads) of `aiohttp`. Together with `ijson` it should allow you to not load the whole json string into memory and stream it th